# How to get items in DynamoDB Table filter based on TimeStamp and an offset of this TimeStamp value?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have DynamoDB table with the following schema:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "SomeTable",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "userid", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "transactionId", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "userid", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "transactionId", AttributeType: "S" },
    ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [ 
        { 
           IndexName: "TransactionIndex",
           KeySchema: [ 
              { 
                 AttributeName: "transactionId",
                 KeyType: "HASH"
              },
              { 
                AttributeName: "productId",
                KeyType: "RANGE"
             }
           ],
           Projection: { 
              ProjectionType: "ALL"
           },
           ProvisionedThroughput: { 
              ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
              WriteCapacityUnits: 10
           }
        }
     ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};
```

I am looking to query this table, filtered based on time value, however I cannot find any documentation on how to modify this value in the FilterExpression. The idea is to find all the rows where the expiry_date_ms value is about to expiry, or has just expired (i.e. 1 day before or 1 day after), as follow:

```
var startoffset = 86400000;         // one day before
var endoffset = 86400000;         // one day after

var params = { 
    TableName: "SomeTable", 
    FilterExpression: "#tm between :start and :end'",    
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#tm": "expiry_date_ms" }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":start": "expiry_date_ms" - startoffset, ":end": "expiry_date_ms" + endoffset }  
}; 

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log(params);
        console.log("Scan succeeded.");        
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log("Item :" + JSON.stringify(item));           
        });
    }
});
```

Maybe I have the logic completely wrong and there is a better/clever way to run such query or what's the best method, Scan or Query in my case. Any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It'd be best to know what your schema looks like. More than likely the better route will be to model your data differently for this access pattern, but without knowing what the current data model looks like and the access patterns you are trying to do, it is difficult to know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. - @Kirk, I have modified the question to include the DB schema.